# What is the meaning of "your argument is invalid"?

Tags: idioms

Does the phrase "your argument is invalid" has some idiomatic meaning?

Because I am often seeing it in places where its literal meaning doesn't make sense.

In some cases I felt it means something like *'Nuff said*. Is that correct?

For example,

[image: this meme]

Comment: Rathony, Doesn't it imply, "Your argument has never been invalid to the extent it is right now"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the assumption that a literal meaning of *invalid* makes no sense in the given context.

Comment: Now, now Rath: don't get ahead of yourself. It may not imply any ultimate peak, merely a hitherto unprecedented one.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not idiomatic, it is literal:

***[Invalid](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/invalid)*** (not valid):

> - An invalid opinion, argument, etc. is not correct, usually because it is not logical or not based on correct information:
>     *an invalid argument*.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Thanks. Is it used in this meme because the picture is not logical? :/

Comment: Dude: it's a joke; it pretends that the weird picture invalidates an argument. It's literal, it's just absurd.

Answer (score 0):

I've always taken it as a sign that the poster feels that the argument has gone beyond the boundaries of proper, logical, argument─e.g. by being based on an appeal to authority or an actual *ad hominem* pseudo-argument─so that one *might as well* say 'That this picture of Nicholas Cage with hair that looks like a bird exists "proves" that you are wrong.'.

Comment: Welcome!  Can you clarify to answer the question about the idiomatic usage?